# "Wapache" how can we upgrade php from 5.0 to 5.2?

Tags: php, apache, upgrade

In my practice of programming and server managment i always find everything on google, but this time, i`m stumbled.

Apache is giving us there product "Wapache" which allows us to run web technology applications throught executable exe application. Everything works just perfect, you can specify window types to use and fully manage everything you need to see to look like an app.

But, it has php 5.0 which is kinda anoying, i would like to upgrade to 5.2 or higher when theres a newer version, but how do you do it?

The project page: http://wapache.sourceforge.net/

Thank you for replies, best regards.
Edgars Kohs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing module file under modules folder? download php 5.2.x and replace the mod file of it with one in wapache installation.

Comment: You mean "C:\wapache\modules\php5apache2.dll" as a module to change?
And ".:/php5.dll" from php sources for windows? + rename it as "php5apache2.dll" ?